# Android Device that supports concurrent capture from two rear facing cameras

Tags: android, android-camera2

I wanted to know if anyone has had success concurrently capturing images or videos on an Android device from 2 rear cameras, using this API: https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/concurrent-streaming . The phone I had available to test (S21) supported the API, but the only pairs of cameras supported were front+rear facing combos. In kotlin, the code to get the supported pairs is:

```
val cameraManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val concurrentCameras = cameraManager.concurrentCameraIds
```

Hoping someone has a newer Samsung, Xiaomi, or Huawei phone to test if the API is supported? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If the features of the cameras provide functionality, you can check them as follows.

```
 fun CameraManager.directCamera(cameraId: String): LensDirect {
        val lensFacing = getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        return when (lensFacing) {
            CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_FRONT -> LensDirect.FRONT
            CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK -> LensDirect.BACK
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown direction")
        }
    }
```

> Query the capabilities of a camera device. These capabilities are
> immutable for a given camera.
>
> From API level 29, this function can also be used to query the
> capabilities of physical cameras that can only be used as part of
> logical multi-camera. These cameras cannot be opened directly via
> openCamera(String, CameraDevice.StateCallback, Handler)
>
> Also starting with **API level 29**, while most basic camera information
> is still available even without the CAMERA permission, some values are
> not available to apps that do not hold that permission. The keys not
> available are listed by
> **CameraCharacteristics#getKeysNeedingPermission**.